# List Detective Process

Tags: journeybuilder, sms

I am just wondering exactly when List Detective kicks in. I have a journey that sends an email and an sms to a customer. After checking a customer, I identified an email address that is not allowed. However, the customer phone number was ok. It looks like the customer did not even enter the journey as they did not get an sms. Is it then the case, that if LD identifies an invalid email address, it will not enter the journey even for an sms send? thanks

Answer (score 0):

List Detective errors are hard errors that eject a contact from a Journey. If the contact is ejected at the email step they would not continue on to the SMS step.